# Why is the advanced attributes button sometimes replaced by an archive checkbox?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, archiving

Sometimes when viewing a file or folder's properties, I see an **Advanced** button listed under **Attributes**.

[image: Advanced button in file properties]

Other times, the advanced button is replaced by an **Archive** checkbox.

[image: Archive checkbox in file properties]

**Why do file attributes sometimes display an archive checkbox instead of the advanced options button?**

Comment: Just another UX disaster of Windows Explorer. The usual.

Comment: @GrasDouble so can you suggest a better way to include compress/encrypt/archive/index flag on a single window?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Aways show the ***Advanced*** button, then grey out the options that aren't available. The hover text could include a brief explanation as to why the options are unavailable.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The **Advanced** dialog is shown only if the file is stored on a drive which supports compression or encryption.

[image: Advanced options dialog]

If the volume doesn't support either compression or encryption, the **Archive** checkbox will be shown instead.

**FAT** filesystems ***do not*** support compression or encryption, meaning files display an **Archive** checkbox.

**NTFS** filesystems ***do*** support both compression and encryption, meaning files display the **Advanced** button.

- *Source: [Raymond Chen, Microsoft Developer Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090219-00/?p=19093/)*