# Advanced Attributes button not available on NTFS disk

Tags: windows-7, windows, ntfs

I have a problem that is similar to one described in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1221506/why-is-the-advanced-attributes-button-sometimes-replaced-by-an-archive-checkbox), but in my case it's *Advanced Attributes* dialog isn't available for files and folders on NTFS disk; *Archive* checkbox is shown instead.

This is 4 Tb USB 3.0 disk that is recognized as local (not removable). It has GUID partition and contains 4 Tb NTFS disk (not FAT32 or exFAT).

Other NTFS disks have *Advanced Attributes* dialog where it's expected.

As the answer in linked question states,

> The Advanced dialog is shown only if the file is stored on a drive which supports compression or encryption.

What can be the problem here? Are there conditions under which NTFS disk doesn't support compression or encryption?

Comment: An image of the partitions on the disk would be helpful

Comment: @Ramhound I'm unable to provide it because I currently have problems with Disk Management utility (not related to the problem), but it's simple volume (not dynamic or so), non-bootable, primary partition. The only thing that differs is that this is GPT disk and other disks on this PC that don't have this problem are MBR.

Comment: There are third-party partition applications that can provide that screenshot